# How to move file contents deeper without copying

Tags: linux, shell, mv, directory-structure

I have files in `/home/jjblack/foo/`. I want to move all the contents of this directory into `/home/jjblack/foo/bar/`.

I am unable to copy the contents elsewhere as there is not enough disk space. I am able to

```
mv /home/jjblack/foo /home/jjblack/xyz
mkdir /home/jjblack/foo
mv /home/jjblack/xyz /home/jjjblack/foo/bar
```

However is there is a more elegant one-line solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of commands that you show, here with shortened pathnames assuming `jjblack` is the current user (use `~jjblack` in place of `~` otherwise):

```bash
mv ~/foo ~/xyz
mkdir ~/foo
mv ~/xyz ~/foo/bar
```

I would argue that this is rather elegant and that the only thing this lacks is a couple of safety checks to make sure none of the later commands is executed if a previous command fails:

```bash
[ ! -e ~/xyz ] &&
mv ~/foo ~/xyz &&
mkdir ~/foo &&
mv ~/xyz ~/foo/bar
```

or, if you need it on a single line:

```bash
[ ! -e ~/xyz ] && mv ~/foo ~/xyz && mkdir ~/foo && mv ~/xyz ~/foo/bar
```

This is now a single "complete command" (in the shell grammar sense) consisting of an "AND-list" of "simple commands".

This avoids any issue with hidden names, it doesn't expand globbing patterns resulting in a list of potentially millions of names, it does not try to move individual files (slower than moving a single directory), and it does not use any large amount of extra storage. It also successfully moves the meta-data (ownership and permissions etc.) of the original `foo` directory to the new name `bar`.

The other way to perform the same operation is by creating the new parent directory first and renaming it at the end.  This allows us to get rid of the `-e` test as `mkdir` would fail if the `~/xyz` name already exists.

```bash
mkdir ~/xyz &&
mv ~/foo ~/xyz/bar &&
mv ~/xyz ~/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/jjblack/foo
mkdir bar && mv * bar/
```

Comment: Note that if the directory contains hidden names, then these would not be moved by the command that you show. There might also be complications if any name starts with a dash.

Comment: This will also try to move `bar` into `bar`, which will cause `mv` to complain and exit with a status of 1 (indicating an error).